# Given two geographic points on earth what is the best way to find a point in the middle given a distance from the starting point?

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, spherical-coordinates

The purpose of this question is to use the function to generate a trajectory for plane objects to travel from one city to another in Google Earth using a type of animation. I am coding my program in Java but I can take other forms. I ask for the best way because I'd like for it to be relatively fast and smooth, so accuracy is not of the highest priority.

Comment: A common solution in computer graphics is [spherical linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), but you will have to convert the points to Cartesian coordinates ($x,y,z$) first if they are given in latitude-longitude form.

Comment: Quite a few helpful resources here : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: locate the two positions  in a maximal circle of the sphere, this is an analog of a meridional one